# How to loop through a set and get the last value of set

Tags: python

I want to Loop through a set named `Group` and get the last value of the Group.

I tried the following code:

```
m = list()
for i in range (1,6):
    Group = base.Getentity(constants.ABAQUS, "SET", i)
    m.append(Group)
    print(Group)
```

And my result is following:

```
<Entity:0*17a:id:1>
<Entity:0*14g:id:2>
<Entity:0*14f:id:3>
<Entity:0*14a:id:4>
None
None
```

In the above code I have used a range of `(1,6)` as an example but in reality I wouldn't know the range number so I'd like to write code such that doesn't use `range`/`xrange` or `print`.

Even though the code is written in Python my question is more general.

Comment: The last element can be got with `m[-1]`? In your code above you append `set` to `m` but `set` is not defined as far as I can see

Comment: sorry its a mistake , it is not set,  it is group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_set = {1, 'hello', 12.4}
print(my_set)
print(list(my_set).pop())

--output:--
{1, 12.4, 'hello'}
hello
```

---

```
my_set = {1, 'hello', 12.4}
print(my_set)

while True:
    try: 
        val = my_set.pop()
        print(val)
    except KeyError:
        print("last: {}".format(val))
        break

--output:--
{1, 12.4, 'hello'}
1
12.4
hello
last: hello
```

Comment: Sorry, the Problem here is getting the set becoz i dont know how to define set , It may have lots of elements

Comment: @Agastya Peela, Huh?  Your question was: *I want to Loop through a set, and get the last value of the set.*

Comment: I think the problem is that he has to generate the list first. The get the last item from that list.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't make lot of sense.

```
m.append(set)
```

is not doing anything, it just appends the python-class-type `set` to the `m`, not the value you get from `base.Getentity`

But back to the question.

You could try using a while loop.

Like so:

```
m = []
i = 0
while True:
   group = base.Getentity(constants.ABAQUS,"SET",i)
   if group is None:
       break
   i += 1
   m.append(group)
print(m[-1])
```

Comment: A set can have None as an element.

Comment: @7stud `group is None` is different than `None in group`. A set can have None as an element of it's group but it can't be None and a set at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I simple iterative solution like this probably could do your job:

```
last_group = None
i = 0
while True:
    next_group = base.Getentity(constants.ABAQUS, "SET", i)
    i += 1
    if next_group is None:
        break
    last_group = i, next_group

print last_group
```

Comment: `i` is not defined ;)

Comment: if i += 1 is not required, you could do this more efficient by doing i += x, if the return value is None, do i -= x/2 if it's not None, do i += x/4 and so on... :)

Comment: yeah, i is not defined and i dont know the definition

Comment: Hi Glaslos, in that case what would be my x value, like how to define x value?

Comment: Sorry I overlooked this `i` argument in `Getentity`. I accepted the proposal of `Glaslos` still this solution is an assumption as we don't know what and how this argument is used. Is it the position of the entry? Are we talking for zero-based or one-based list?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `i` is unknown and you have to iterate over `i` to get you final result:

Generating your values and printing the last:

```
i = 1
last_group = None
while True:
    group = base.Getentity(constants.ABAQUS,"SET", i)
    if not group:
        print 'Last item: {0} with i: {1}'.format(last_group, i)
    last_group = group
    i += 1
```

We are not keeping a list of results therefore keep a low memory footprint if `i` can be large.